# MonoTouch NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.AddObserver now obsolete?

Tags: xamarin.ios, obsolete

I'm just wondering what the modern equivalent of:

```
NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.AddObserver("UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification", receivedRotate);
```

would be. It says its obsolete and that I should use AddObserver, but I'm not sure what to use for the IntPtr context var.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need the IntPtr variant, if you read the Obsolete method it says:

"Use AddObserver(NSString, Action) instead"

So what you want is

```
NotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.AddObserver (UIDevice.OrientationDidChangeNotification, receivedRotate);
```

Comment: You're right of course. This worked. Don't know why I didnt put this together myself!